# strange output when using with vector iterato

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am getting strange output when running following code. 
In the getMeanGap function given below, it prints different vector element when comparing with vector elements printed in the calling function

```
//===Main Function========

    cout << ">>" << endl;
    for (typename vector<Type>::iterator it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); ++it)
    {
      cout << it->x << "\t" << it->y << endl; // "\t" << it->width << "\t" << it->height << endl;
    }

    cout << getMeanGap(v1) << endl;

//=======================
```

the getMeanGap function given below

```
template<typename Type>
float VIDSegment::getMeanGap(const vector<Type> & vec) const
{
  if (vec.size() < 2) return 0.0;
  cout << "----" <<endl;
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (typename vector<Type>::const_iterator it = vec.begin() - 1; it != vec.end(); ++it)
  {
    typename vector<Type>::const_iterator temp = it;
    temp++;
    cout << it->x << "\t" << it->y << endl;
    sum += ( (temp->x) - (it->x) - (it->width));
  }
  return float(sum / (vec.size() - 1));
}
```

While running above code I am getting following result

```
>>
26  51
56  19
112 23
175 25
211 26
331 23
379 23
424 23
471 23
----
0 0    // ??
26  51
56  19
112 23
175 25
211 26
331 23
379 23
424 23
471 23
```

May I know the reason for the above output ??

Comment: Are you honestly surprised you get weird output when accessing one element *before* the start of your container?

Comment: `it = vec.begin() - 1` -- this is undefined behavior. Maybe you intended to use `temp` instead of `it` within the function. But why are you initializing it in that weird way to begin with?

Comment: I just read in C++ Primer that accessing on element before the iterator gives weird output and doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Ohh I need, vec.end() - 1 ::Now I got it

Comment: No that is wrong. If you need to look through all the elements in a vector, you start with vec.begin() and you check the ending iterator iter != vec.end().

Comment: Iterators *should* be used primarily inside of algorithms. To print the contents of the vector, you *should* really just be passing `begin()` and `end()` to the correct algorithm (in this case, `std::copy`, with an `std::ostream_iterator` as the destination).

Comment: I need to Iterate only from first element to last - 1 element

Comment: You could do that deepak... but you could also observe that the sum of the gaps between adjactent elements is equal to the gap between the first and last element, and reduce that sum by the "width" values per-element (bar the last).

Comment: In my code Type is CvRect structure, with memeber variables x, y, width and height. Where x,y represent top left corner. I am initially summing the free gap between two adjacent rectangles(CvRect), and finally dividing the sum by (total rectangles -1)::  Is there any logical mistake in my code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has undefined behaviour because you are trying to access invalid iterator

```
vec.begin() - 1
```

and use it in statement

```
cout << it->x << "\t" << it->y << endl;
```

in loop

```
  for (typename vector<Type>::const_iterator it = vec.begin() - 1; it != vec.end(); ++it)
  {
    typename vector<Type>::const_iterator temp = it;
    temp++;
    cout << it->x << "\t" << it->y << endl;
    sum += ( (temp->x) - (it->x) - (it->width));
  }
```